# When is the code for an inner function "available" for the outer function to use in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-function

Hello I am working on algorithms and I have written a working version of quickSort, see code below:

```
def quickSort(mylist, l, r):
    if l < r:
        q = partition(mylist, l, r)
        quickSort(mylist, l, q-1)
        quickSort(mylist, q+1, r)

    def partition(mylist, l, r):
        i = l-1
        j = l
        while j < r:
            if mylist[j] < mylist[r]:
                i += 1
                mylist[i], mylist[j] = mylist[j], mylist[i]
            j += 1
        mylist[i+1], mylist[j] = mylist[j], mylist[i+1]
        return i+1

mylist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20,22]
l = 0
r = len(mylist) -1
quickSort(mylist, l, r)
```

However when I run this I get

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'partition' referenced before assignment

And the fix is to move the definition of the inner function `partition` at the top of `quickSort` so that it does not call `partition` before it is defined.

But I don't understand why, my guess is that inner functions do not "exist" before the outer one is actually executed. Can someone please clarify this point for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you can see functions just as callable variables.

For example you can assign them to variable names, like in the following example:

```
def example_function():
    print("Hello world!")

example_var = example_function
example_var() # call the variable!
```

Just as you can reassign variables, you can also reassign functions definitions, which means that the definition of a function is not global:

```
def my_function():
    print("first")

my_function() # prints "first"

def my_function():
    print("redefined")

my_function() # prints "redefined"
```

So just as you wouldn't expect something like this ...

```
# a _not_ defined above
print(a) # even if this worked, should it print "3" or "4"?
a = 3
a = 4
```

... to work, because the variable is not defined yet, a call of a function, that has not been defined yet, is also not valid.

Like with any other variable, a definition stated in the future is also only valid in that future and it will be obsolete as soon as it is redefined.